# Can I swap the private and public key within ZeroMQ

Tags: c, encryption, zeromq

At the moment, I am investigating the possibilities to use ZeroMQ with Curve to secure traffic between my publishers and subscribers.

I have successfully implemented a pub sub system which is using CZMQ.

At the moment, my publisher is encrypting the data he wants to send with his private key and subscribers can decrypt this data using the public key of the publisher. This is more 'authenticating' data than 'encrypting' data. Because when there is a Man In The Middle he can still decrypt all the data because the public key of the publisher is public.

I'm coding in C with the latest version of ZeroMQ and CZMQ.

My publisher.c

```
zctx_t* zmq_context = zctx_new();

zauth_t* auth = zauth_new (zmq_context);
zauth_set_verbose (auth, true);
zauth_configure_curve (auth, "*", CURVE_ALLOW_ANY);

zcert_t* pub_cert = zcert_load("cert.key"); // private key of publisher
void* socket = zsocket_new(zmq_context, ZMQ_PUB);
zcert_apply(pub_cert, socket);
zsocket_set_curve_server(socket, true);

//start publishing from here
```

My subscriber.c

```
zctx_t* zmq_context = zctx_new();

zcert_t* sub_cert = zcert_new();
zcert_t* pub_cert = zcert_load("cert.pub"); // public key of publisher
char* pub_key = zcert_public_txt(pub_cert);

void* zmq_s = zsocket_new(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);
zcert_apply(sub_cert, zmq_s);
zsocket_set_curve_serverkey(zmq_s, pub_key);

//start subscribing to topics and receiving messages from here
```

From this point, the publisher is encrypting all the data with his private key and the subscribing is decrypting all the data with the public key of the publisher. I would like to swap this system.

So, I would like to encrypt all the data with the public key of the publisher and decrypt all the data with the private key of the publisher.

I have tested it and changed the `zcert_load("cert.key")` to `zcert_load("cert.pub")` in my publisher.c.

I also changed this code in my subscriber.c:

```
zcert_t* pub_cert = zcert_load("cert.pub"); // public key of publisher
char* pub_key = zcert_public_txt(pub_cert);
```

to this code:

```
zcert_t* pub_cert = zcert_load("cert.key"); // private key of publisher
char* pub_key = zcert_secret_txt(pub_cert);
```

When I run my publisher and subscriber with these code changes, the publisher is constantly giving me the message: `CURVE I: cannot open client HELLO -- wrong server key?`

My question: Is it possibile to use a public key for encrypting data (publisher socket) and the private key for decrypting data (subscriber socket) with the architecture of ZeroMQ and CZMQ ?

Many thanks in advance,
Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the ZeroMQ CURVE mechanism. There are two great articles written about it by Pieter Hintjens, [one is theoretical](http://hintjens.com/blog:48), where you can find this:

> Clients and servers have long-term permanent keys, and for each connection, they create and securely exchange short-term transient keys. Each key is a public/secret keypair, following the elliptic curve security model.
>
> To start a secure connection the client needs the server permanent public key. It then generates a transient key pair and sends a HELLO command to the server that contains its short term public key. The HELLO command is worthless to an attacker; it doesn't identify the client.
>
> The server, when it gets a HELLO, generates its own short term key pair (one connection uses four keys in total), and encodes this new private key in a "cookie", which it sends back to the client as a WELCOME command. It also sends its short term public key, encrypted so only the client can read it. It then discards this short term key pair.
>
> At this stage, the server hasn't stored any state for the client. It has generated a keypair, sent that back to the client in a way only the client can read, and thrown it away.
>
> The client comes back with an INITIATE command that provides the server with its cookie back, and the client permanent public key, encrypted as a "vouch" so only the server can read it. As far as the client is concerned, the server is now authenticated, so it can also send back metadata in the command.
>
> The server reads the INITIATE and can now authenticate the client permanent public key. It also unpacks the cookie and gets its short term key pair for the connection. As far as the server is now concerned, the client is now authenticated, so the server can send its metadata safely. Both sides can then send messages and commands.

So the keys you generate here are not used directly to encrypt data, they are only used to authenticate parties. The handshake process between client and server produces real encryption (and authentication as in MAC) keys that are used to encrypt the data. So if the only concern you have is MITM, you're already protected.

But you can also be concerned about rogue clients, your current scheme allows anyone to connect. This is where [the second article](http://hintjens.com/blog:49) by Pieter Hintjens can help you with "The Ironhouse Pattern". The critical part is to disable `CURVE_ALLOW_ANY` and tell server where to look for client public certificates:

```
//  Tell authenticator to use the certificate store in .curve
zauth_configure_curve (auth, "*", ".curve");
```

Then you generate client key on the client (once! not calling `zcert_new()` for every connection), transfer its public part to the ".curve" directory of your server and load (on the client) that key instead of calling `zcert_new()`.

If you want to make life a bit easier (not needing to transfer public keys from client to server for each client), you can create a "golden" client key pair, get its public part into the ".curve" store and then (via a secure channel, of course) copy the secret key on every client that needs to connect to your publisher.

Comment: Hit the enter button to fast. I already read both the articles from Pieter Hintjens. The thing I'm dealing with is security between two or more machines. You stated I have to transfer the certificate of my client to my server. But in my case I am working with a publish subscribe pattern, which means my subscriber is already up and running before my publisher is up and running. The thing I have is setting up the connection with the servers private key and the subscribers have access through the public key.

Comment: When I put the key on the web (it's a public key, so it's gonna be accessible through whole the network) everyone can authorize to my publisher. So that's why we can use `zauth_configure_curve (auth, "*", ".curve")`, but we can't use this one because then I need to send the public key to my publisher over an insecure network. That's why I thought about using my public key to setup my publisher socket, and use the publishers private key to secure the connection. Because then I can distribute my public key and only subscribers can decrypt data which has been send.

Comment: @RoyLenferink: it doesn't matter who starts first, subscriber or publisher. You just need to have subscriber's key known to your publisher, otherwise there is no way to authenticate subscriber. The one hack you can make to ease the key distribution is to use single key on every client, transferring it to the client via some secure channel when needed (I'll update the answer with that). Other than that, there is no PKI there with CAs or anything like that to sign client's keys independently from server.

Comment: Okay, then this answer my question that it isn't really possible to swap the keys. The only option is using the .curve directory as a publisher and authenticating the subscribers. Thanks Roman